# FOSS Sketch to SVG conversion script

Tags: open-source, svg, file-format, sketch

Is there a free and open-source script that would convert Sketch files (Sketch as in the popular Mac-only vector graphics editor) into SVG files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25224684/is-it-possible-to-convert-a-sketch-file-to-an-svg

Comment: @albert This is specifically asking for an open-source variant. I know there are proprietary solutions out there.